# Needed: Complex SQL Query for Recategorizing Output

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to create a SQL Query that outputs data in a specific format.

Let's assume I have two tables with data as shown:

Table 1:

```
Name    
A       
B       
C
```

Table 2:

```
Name        Address          Category
A           123 One St.      Type1
A           123 One St.      Type1
A           123 One St.      Type1
A           123 One St.      Type2
B           222 Two St.      Type2
B           222 Two St.      Type2
C           77 Three St.     Type1
C           77 Three St.     Type3
C           77 Three St.     Type3
```

I need to generate output in the following format:

```
Name        Address        Type1   Type2  Type3
A           123 One St.    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
B           222 Two St.    FALSE   TRUE   FALSE
C           77 Three St.   TRUE    FALSE  TRUE
```

I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My attempt only gets partway:

```
    select t1.Name, Category="Type1" as Type1, Category="Type2" as Type2,
           Category="Type3" as Type3
    from Table2 t1
    order by Name
```

This falls way short of the goal.

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for conditional aggregation and an inner join.

```
SELECT t2.name,
       t2.address,
       CASE
         WHEN count(CASE t2.category
                      WHEN 'Type1' THEN
                        1
                    END) > 0 THEN
           'TRUE'
         ELSE
           'FALSE'
       END type1,
       CASE
         WHEN count(CASE t2.category
                      WHEN 'Type2' THEN
                        1
                    END) > 0 THEN
           'TRUE'
         ELSE
           'FALSE'
       END type2,
       CASE
         WHEN count(CASE t2.category
                      WHEN 'Type3' THEN
                        1
                    END) > 0 THEN
           'TRUE'
         ELSE
           'FALSE'
       END type3
     FROM table1 t1
          INNER JOIN table2 t2
                     ON t2.name = t1.name
     GROUP BY t2.name,
              t2.address;
```

Comment: Spectacular answer. This hit the mark perfectly. I added:

`ORDER BY t2.name`

and this is spot on 100% working.